# Rendering a gsp not working from controller grails

Tags: grails, gradle, groovy

I am facing an issue that i am not able to render a gsp view from a controller.
I did following :

1) create-app demo

2) grails ( open grails cmd)

3) create-controller check.work

```
package check

class WorkController {
  def index() { render(view:'foo') }
}
```

4) put some content in grails-app/views/work/foo.gsp

5) started grails run-app on 8080

Issue is that if i just render("hello"), it works and prints on browser. But loading gsp file doesn't print any thing and return with 200.

URL used : http://localhost:8080/work/index

Have anyone faced such issue before ?

> Grails Version: 3.1.11
>   | Groovy Version: 2.4.7
>   | JVM Version: 1.8.0_111

Comment: Remove this code in index action  -> render(view:'foo')

Comment: Or create foo.gsp and create foo action in WorkController

Comment: maybe something unusual with the word `work` https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/jdbc/Work.html. Everything you have written if followed should have worked .. so try a new controller Test and see if repeating it in there causes same issue

Comment: See `selecting the view` part of this section of the [doc](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#modelsAndViews)